# functions.php conditional output for a single plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, conditional-content

hope I've asked this correctly. Bizarre situation. I have some non-breaking spaces in my titles for typography reasons. They are added automatically where required in place of normal spaces by the following function...

```
// stop brackets in titles appearing on own line
function clean_orphan_titles($content){

$array = array (

   '{ ' => '{&nbsp;',

   ' }' => '&nbsp;}'

);

$content = strtr($content, $array);

return $content;

}

add_filter('the_title', 'clean_orphan_titles');
```

The problem I have is that one plugin doesn't like this - you can see the result here http://skipology.com/temporary-test-page/ However. If I replace `return $content;` with `return htmlspecialchars($content);` the plugin output renders correctly but the rest of my site displays `&nbsp;` instead of the space.

Can I either create a conditional situation to include both lines with one just targeted at the output of the plugin (Wordpress Popular Posts) or can I create a near duplicate function somehow triggered by the plugin?

I can't target a specific page because all pages will potentially contain this conflict.

Edit - the conflicting output is from the plugin and shows my post titles as generated by the plugin as 'iPhoneography seascape workflow – {�horizon�}' where the � is the `&nbsp;`

Edit2 - That helps. What is the Plugin itself doing to filter the post title?

This is what I can see...

```
// TITLE

$title = ($this->qTrans) ? qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage($p->title) : $p->title;
$title = strip_tags($title);
$title_sub = strip_tags($title);

// truncate title (section on truncating the title here - I don't use)

$title = htmlspecialchars( $title, ENT_QUOTES, $this->charset );
$title_sub = htmlspecialchars( $title_sub, ENT_QUOTES, $this->charset );
$title = apply_filters('the_title', $title, $p->id);
$title_sub = apply_filters('the_title', $title_sub, $p->id);
```

Specifically re character sets we have:

```
var $charset = "UTF-8";
```

and...

```
// set charset
$this->charset = get_bloginfo('charset');
```

and the SQL character set seems to be

```
$sql = "";
$charset_collate = "";
```

Edit 3 - I've just done another test and if I manually insert `&nbsp;` into a title rather than relying on my functions.php code posted above it's rendered perfectly by the plug in. Is there something wrong with the functions.php? My source code shows the correct behaviour as does my site so I'm confused! e.g. this is the title from a post...

`<h1><a href="http://skipology.com/iphone-photography-tip-extend-image-canvas-auto-clone/" title="iPhone photography tip {&nbsp;extend canvas and auto clone&nbsp;}">iPhone photography tip {&nbsp;extend canvas and auto clone&nbsp;}</a><i class="icon-file pull-right"></i></h1>`

Comment: Please add the conflicting code/output directly to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance Chip - post edited. Hope it is what you need.

Comment: That helps. What is the Plugin itself doing to filter the post title?

Comment: Do you also have QTranslate installed? If so, what happens when you disable it?

Comment: No I've never installed QTranslate and I can't see it came as part of my theme.

Comment: I am assuming the backticks in that code are typos?

Comment: Kind of - it was the only way I could get `&nbsp;` to display rather than just ' '. They aren't in the code.

Comment: Removed the backticks. The code still displays correctly.

Comment: Sorry, let's back up. A single `&nbsp;` should be equivalent to a sinlge normal space character. It is when you want multiple spaces that you need the `&nbsp;`, so what is the problem? What is the point of this again?

Comment: Apologies gone mobile but appreciate the support really great. The reason I use nbsp (sorry can't add back ticks) is that I don't want { to appear at end of line or } to appear at start of new line. Nbsp attaches the following / previous word so typographically the line wrap is professional.

Comment: I've ended up manually editing my titles which for whatever reason does not generate the error. I will leave the filter in place to serve as a backup. Mystery but I wonder if it is related to character encoding. Thank you all for your help. Much appreciated.